# Why my static imagea are not displayed?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, static-linking

I'm running a Google App locally.

I have a folder with static images I want to pull. Folder is called "images" (it's in the root)

In my app.yaml I have this code:

```
- url: /images
  static_files: images
  upload: images
```

But when the app is running and trying to grab an image I get 404:

localhost:8080/images/truck.png

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Using this:

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /resources
  static_dir: resources

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Ensure that the resources url is before the /.* url.

I have my project set up as follows

```
/test
/test/resources
/test/resources/images
/test/resources/images/myimage.png
app.yaml
main.py
```

Comment: This is how I have mine set up and it works fine.  Make sure you have the -url under the "handlers:" heading, but before the catch all "- url: /.*"  The route may be matching your /images/truck.png on a different handler.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. I just didn't know that you have to put it before  the ".*" handler